# How to understand the first sentence in chapter 13 of Tess of the d'Urbervilles?

Tags: meaning, literature

> The event of Tess Durbeyfield's return from the manor of her bogus kinsfolk was rumoured abroad, if rumour be not too large a word for a space of a square mile.

I have several doubts:

1. Whether "if rumour be..." can be replaced with "if rumour is..." and why?
2. What is the meaning of "too large a word for a space of a square mile"? Is it slang or something else?

Comment: Is the size of the manor ever referenced?  I think that is the square mile here.

Comment: Those look like questions, not doubts. Doubts are things you think may be not quite right. Grammatically, doubts are associated with assertions, not questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The event of Tess Durbeyfield's return from the manor of her bogus kinsfolk was rumoured abroad, if rumour be not too large a word for a space of a square mile.

In this sentence, "rumor be not" is an obsolete use of the infinitive form.   You're absolutely correct, replace "be" with "is" in your head and do not use "be" like this in writing or speaking.  It's just antiquated English.

> too large a word for a space of a square mile

When Tess returns to her father's cottage after being assaulted, the townsfolk have already gossiped about it.  They live in a small town that is very close to the manor.

The intention here is subtle:  Hardy uses the phrase "rumored abroad", which conjures the image of a well-known socialite traveling about and being widely discussed - in contrast with the actual description of the size of the town - less than a square mile.  Thus, he ironically emphasizes how different Tess' and the townsfolks' social standing is from that "wealthy socialite" archetype, whose place the Stokes vainly aspire to as Tess has vainly aspired to theirs, as well.

A whole lot of implied meaning in very few words!

Comment: I think "abroad" is used in an archaic sense of "widely", not with reference to foreign lands.  It's the rumour that is spreading "abroad", not her travels.  But there is definitely irony is saying that the rumour is spreading widely and then saying it is only really circulating within a square mile.

Comment: I agree with your reading of "abroad".  And it is certainly the rumor of her encounter with Alec / those troubles / her sexual assault that is going abroad, and not her person.  The jet-set image is modern, and mine - not Hardy's!  Apologies if that was confusing.  I edited "the world" to "about" above to remove the confusion.  I'm not even sure the other meaning of "abroad" was in use.  But that has no bearing on the rest of what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. My reply is a bit long; others may offer more concise replies.

The subjunctive tense is used to express a wish or desire, an improbability. The subjunctive form of *to be* is *be*. *If rumour be* implies that the writer wishes to consider rumour as applicable word, even though perhaps it is not really applicable.

And what “rumour” is being talked about? Merely that she had returned from the manor. And who is hearing the rumour? Only those who live in the small square mile around her home. The small and insignificant area means that the news cannot really be termed *rumour*, which is why Hardy uses the subjunctive construction as above.

Comment: Two comments. (1) The important point you should add is that the use of the subjunctive here is old-fashioned and in fact we would normally say "If rumour is".  (2) I don't think the subjunctive is properly a tense.

Comment: I disagree with this.  This use is exactly like the infinitive form "be" in "if music be the food of love" - very close in meaning to just using "is".  There is no "wish". but perhaps carries a state aspect slightly more like 'ser' than 'estar' in Spanish.  It's not subjunctive.  We don't use it anymore.

Comment: True, this type of subjunctive is used here to express uncertainty rather than a wish ("If it be", "whether it be").  In modern English  this type of subjunctivity is used mostly to express orders or demands ("I ordered that he leave").  There might be rare cases where it seems to express a wish (and those demands might be wishes of a sort).

Comment: Example from Donne with no trace of uncertainty:  "Death be not proud /  though some have called thee".

Comment: True, it doesn't always express uncertainty, but that's its purpose in Hardy's sentence.  And not solely because of the "if".  Even today we can just about say something like "Be he dead or alive, ...".

Comment: @BadZen Surely that is a command to Death not to be proud, not a subjunctive?